Get a list of Vertex Groups filtered by name in Python
For Vertex Group there is a filter by name. Is there any way to get the filtered result in Python? Because object.vertex_groups provides a list of all vertex groups, not just the filtered ones.


using pure python to search for any occurrence of a partial string in the vertex group names:
import bpy    

obj = bpy.data.objects['Sphere']
vgs = list(obj.vertex_groups) 
ptrn = 'aa'

result = [vg for vg in vgs if ptrn in vg.name] # wanted contained anywhere in string

for r in result:
    print( r.name )

result is a list of vertex groups who's name contains the letter.
Or you can use the lambda:
     result = list(filter(lambda x: ptrn in x.name, vgs))
If you wanted startsWith(ptrn):
     result = list(filter(lambda x: x.name.startswith(ptrn), vgs))

I didn't mention, but it is also expected in the future to use other filters in addition to the name: use_filter_invert, use_filter_sort_alpha, use_filter_sort_reverse. Thus, everything that is in the default UIList. And for subsequent work, the result that is obtained in a combination of all filters is important. Order matters too. [a,b]!=[b,a]

@VadimTss -- as per my example solution, it is all just in python once you get past how to access names.  not in to invert, etc. google away your issues!

It is important that the user can use the GUI provided with the UIList for filter. It turns out that you are proposing to duplicate all the filters in Python to calculate the final list?

@VadimTss -- well this appears to be veering off from your original question that I answered.  I'm not suggesting you create any more code or filters than you need.
